# How to solve unable to drive module description for ../selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Unable to derive module descriptor for C:\Users\admin\eclipse-workspace\Testing\lib\selenium-server-standalone.jar

```
Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: Provider class org.eclipse.jetty.http.Http1FieldPreEncoder not in module
```

```
package Testing;

import com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium;
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.Selenium;

public class Testing {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
        Selenium selenium= new DefaultSelenium("localhost",4444,"firefox","http://www.calculator.net");
        selenium.start();
        selenium.open("/");
        selenium.windowMaximize();
        selenium.click("xpath=.//*[@id=''hl3']/li[3]/a"); 
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        selenium.focus("id=cpar1");
         selenium.type("css=input[id=\"cpar1\"]", "10"); 
        selenium.focus("id=cpar2"); 
         selenium.type("css=input[id=\"cpar2\"]", "50"); 
         (selenium).click("xpath=.//*[@id='content']/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td/input[2]"); 
         // verify if the result is 5
         Thread.sleep(4000);
         String result = selenium.getText("xpath=.//*[@id='content']/p[2]/font/b");
         //String result = selenium.getValue("xpath=.//*[@id='cpar3']");
         System.out.println("Result:"+result);

         if (result.equals("5")/*== "5"*/){
            System.out.println("Pass");
         }
         else{
            System.out.println("Fail");
         }

    }

}
```

[image: image of source code and error]

Comment: make sure lib jars is on your build path.

Comment: Try to use a dependency manager like maven or gradle instead of download the jar and add in project

Answer (score 1):

1. I would recommend reconsidering using [Selenium Remote Control](https://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/remote-control/) as it is quite outdated approach which is no longer supported, current stable version of Selenium Java client is [3.141.59](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java/3.141.59) and it provides [WebDriver API](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp) which is a [W3C Standard](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/) as of now.
2. Once you implement option 1 get rid of those [Thread.sleep()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(long)) as it's a some form of a performance [anti-pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern), go for [Explicit Wait](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp) instead, check out [How to use Selenium to test web applications using AJAX technology](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/ajax_technology_selenium/) for comprehensive explanation and code examples.
3. It's better to use a dependency management solution like [Apache Maven](http://maven.apache.org) which will automatically detect and download your project [transitive dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies). A relevant pom.xml file would be something like:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
       <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

       <groupId>com.example</groupId>
       <artifactId>selenium</artifactId>
       <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
       <build>
           <plugins>
               <plugin>
                   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                   <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                   <configuration>
                       <source>8</source>
                       <target>8</target>
                   </configuration>
               </plugin>
           </plugins>
       </build>

       <dependencies>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
               <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
               <version>3.141.59</version>
           </dependency>
       </dependencies>

   </project>
   ```